# Chrooted user can't login with SSH

Tags: centos, ssh, chroot

I created a new user with no shell access like this:

```
useradd  -g www -d /www/user01 -p ****** -s /sbin/nologin user01
```

Then in my `sshd_config` I add those lines:

```
AllowUsers user01 user02 manager

Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp

Match User user01
  ChrootDirectory /www/user01
  PasswordAuthentication yes
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

The problem is I got Access denied every time I log in with putty, is there any misconfiguration?

**UPDATE:**

It appears that the only user can ssh is the `root` user, even adding the new user to `AllowUsers` directive.

Comment: Did you correct `/www/user01` owner and permissions?

Comment: @Glueon Yes, I chown `/www` to `root:root`, and `/www/user01` to `user01:www`, but then I lost readability for nginx without to mention I am still can't login via ssh.

Comment: Those are not the correct permissions. ChrootDirectory: "Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after authentication.  All components of the pathname must be root-owned directories that are not writable by any other user or group."

Comment: `I am still can't login via ssh.` why would you think that you would be able to login with ssh/putty?  You have set a force command to only permit sftp clients.

Comment: @Woredache Even removing `ForceCommand internal-sftp`, or keeping it and login with sftp client WinSCP, it fails.

Answer (score 2):

`/sbin/nologin` is  your problem.

You have two options for bash: `/bin/bash` and `/bin/bash` (chrooted).

Basically, chrooted bash is for avoiding mishaps.

http://docs.1h.com/Chrooting

Comment: The authorized used should only able to upload and download files, so a shell is not necessary to grant.